# How to implement a general class for singleton?

Tags: dart, design-patterns

I've been trying to implement a state management project for my design patterns course. I have implemented the singleton because I know that's essential for keeping state of a class. What I would like to do is: Create a general class, so that others could use it in their projects. How do I do that? My code so far:

```
class StateManager{
  static final StateManager _instance = StateManager._singleton();

  StateManager._singleton();

  factory StateManager(){
    return _instance;
  }

}
```

My other solution to try and make it general:

```
class AppProvider extends StateManager<AppProvider>{

  int i = 10;
  String data = "adas";

  


}

class StateManager<T extends AppProvider>{
  static final StateManager _instance = StateManager._singleton();

  StateManager._singleton();

  factory StateManager(){
    return _instance;
  }


}
```

I want the AppProvider class to be the client class, and I want the StateManager to automatically handle the fact that AppProvider should be a singleton, and maintain the state of AppProvider.. I really don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing a class to be a singleton *through inheritance alone* is not going to work. That's not something that the language supports. Constructors are not inherited, neither are static members, and you need those to access the singleton.

In order to be able to create an instance of a class at all, the class needs a generative constructor.
That generative constructor *will* create a new instance every time it's invoked, because that's what generative constructors do.
For a subclass to be able to extend a class, the superclass must have an accessible generative constructor too, but at least the superclass can be made `abstract`.

In order to force a class to be a singleton (if you *really* want that, because a singleton is really something of an anti-pattern; it makes the class act like it's just a bunch of global variables, and that makes testing harder), each such class needs to have a public static way to access or create the instance, and a private generative constructor.

So, basically, your first approach does what is needed, and since the constructors are not inherited, you need to do that for every singleton class, and there is nothing useful to inherit.
So, there is nothing you can do with inheritance to make singleton-ness be inherited, and you can't even *help* because everything a singleton needs is *static*.

A different approach is to make the state classes entirely private, so you don't have to worry about someone else creating instances, and give them a *constant* generative constructor each, and then only refer to them using `const _ThisState()` or `const _ThatState()`.
This puts the responsibility on the user (you!) to only create one instance of each state object, but it also gives a very *easy* way to do that, because `const _ThisState()` will provide the same instance every time.

Or use the enum pattern, and have:

```dart
abstract class State {
 static const State thisState = const _ThisState();
 static const State thatState = const _ThatState();
 const State._();
 void handle(Context context, Object argument);
}
class _ThisState implements State {
  const _ThisState();
  void handle(Context context, Object argument) { ... }
}
class _ThatState implements State {
  const _ThatState();
  void handle(Context context, Object argument) { ... }
}
```

and then just refer to the state instances as `State.thisState`. I find that more readable than creating instances of seemingly unrelated classes.